# In SPD 2010, using a local variable with email addresses with semicolons renders all email after the first with a square character?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

In SPD 2010, using a local variable with email addresses to populate with semicolons renders all [image: screenshot] email after the first email address with a square

What is in the local variable:
john.doe;jane.nelson;jack.edgar

What I get when email sent ( and only sent to first ) because the other 2 malformed.

john.doe; [image: screenshot] jane.nelson; [image: screenshot] jack.edgar

I've tried return field as "email address with semi-colon delimited" and it errors out** ( workflow - cancels immediately . Anyway I can get this to work with return field as string?

** Error
Coercion Failed: Unable to transform the input lookup data into the requested type.

Answer (score 0):

OK duh! but might help someone else. The white squares were for two addresses not in my domain. It's a Microsoft feature that had it green when you're online, red in meeting..etc....the blank square was for one misconfigured address and the other was for a gmail. It was working after all using "string".